# Get GA impressions between given datetime range via API

Tags: php, google-api, google-analytics-api

We want to get the impression from Google Analytics for a domain between 2023-04-06 03:12:26 and 2023-04-06 05:12:26.

How can I get this data via GA API?

We already tried with the start and end date filters in Y-m-d format. But we need the data for given Y-m-d H:i:s date format.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: _"Any help would be appreciated"_ - and so would be, if you showed a bit of effort, before you come here and ask such a plain "how can I" question. Please also see, [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1427878)

Comment: @CBroe I am here because I didn't find any pointers on how to pass datetime in GA API. I know I can use date format in Y-m-d. But I need  the data within a date and time range

Comment: If they would actually offer anything like this, then I would expect to find it listed in the same place, where using a date range is explained - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/DateRange Since there is no such thing mentioned anywhere, I would then assume that this does not actually exist.

Answer (score 1):

> But we need the data for given Y-m-d H:i:s

This is not posible.

## UA

For Universal analytics using the [Google Analytics reporting api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/DateRange) this is not possible.

> DateRange
> A contiguous set of days: startDate, startDate + 1 day, ..., endDate. The start and end dates are specified in ISO8601 date format YYYY-MM-DD.

Start date and end date do not support time it is a date.

## GA4

For Ga4 accounts using the [Google analytics data api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/DateRange) the same holds true start date and end date are dates and not date time.